# Bootstrap 3 row div is taller than content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue on a site where my "row" div is taller than the content in columns inside the row. When I inspect the CSS of the affected pages I'm not finding anything that would be setting a min-height but that is what it's acting like, because if add enough content to a child column it is working correctly.

Here is a link to an affected page: http://www.co.kittitas.wa.us/cds/building/inspection-schedule.aspx

The large space between:

```html
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
        <a href="inspection-request.aspx">
            <img alt="Schedule and inspection" src="/images/cds/inspectionSchedule_01.gif" width="200" height="46" /></a><br />
        <a href="inspection-schedule.aspx">
            <img alt="View the inspection schedule" src="/images/cds/inspectionSchedule_02.gif" width="200" height="23" /></a>
        <br />
        <span class="note">Inspections will not be scheduled for<br />
            <a href="/boc/closures.aspx">days the Permit Center is closed</a>.</span>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
    <p>
        All calendars are subject to change without notice. Late additions to the calendars may not be published
        to this web site. Inspections are not necessarily listed in the order in which they will be performed.
    </p>
     <hr />
    <div class="alert-danger col-sm-12">
        <p>
CDS Building Inspections and Plan Review services will be closed March 14th through the 16th for staff training. We will do our best to accommodate your schedule before and after. Please plan accordingly. Our front counter will still be open for plan submittal and pick up. 
        </p>
    </div></div></div>
```

and:

```html
<h3>Inspection Hours</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>June - August: 7am to 4pm</li>
        <li>September - May: 8am to 5pm (If our vehicles cannot safely make it to your project due to snow and ice in higher elevations, we will not perform the inspection. Please have all access roads and driveways plowed clear so we can get to the job site. We apologize but we cannot ride in your vehicles, all-terrain vehicles or snowmobiles.)</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
```

is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: given link is not working. Loading for a long time

Comment: That's a security issue. we have limited traffic to the site to North America only.

Comment: Ditto to the loading issue. Hard to solve an issue I cant see.

Comment: I have figured out what the issue is, but not how I am going to fix it. I get it that you can't help if you can't see it.